# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' Smarty PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, smarty

Hi everyone I have a little problem here!

I have declared an array

```
class CommonArray {
    public static $foundedyear_array = array_combine(range(date("Y"), 1944), range(date("Y"), 1944)); 

}
```

At Controller I call it out like this

```
$FoundedYearArr = CommonArray::$foundedyear_array;
$this->view->assign("FoundedYearArr", $FoundedYearArr );
```

Then it bugs
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in

```
public static $foundedyear_array = array_combine(range(date("Y"), 1944), range(date("Y"), 1944));
```

How can I fix that to get the array out?
Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs for object property syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) read:

> declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value

Which means you cannot use functions to initialize class properties. Change it to a function:

```
class CommonArray {
    public static function foundedyear_array() {
        return array_combine(range(date("Y"), 1944), range(date("Y"), 1944));
    } 
}
```

Then call it as

```
$FoundedYearArr = CommonArray::foundedyear_array();
```

Comment: This offers a solutions, but should also try to explain why the problem happens.

Comment: Thanks @MatteoTassinari, do you reckon the explanation is good enough?

Comment: I'd say it is! :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have resolved